# How do you display images whose path start with "file:///" ? full path be like "file:///storage/of/image.jpeg" in android platform using Cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js, cordova, quasar

I used `cordova-plugin-file` to download images. The code below is how I download:

```
downloadImageToLocal(imageUrl, imageName) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
        cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory,
        function (rootdir) {
            rootdir.getDirectory(
                "images",
                { create: true },
                function (folderDir) {
                    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
                    fileTransfer.download( 
                        imageUrl,
                        cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory+"images/"+imageName,
                        function (theFile) {
                            console.log("Download is successful");
                            /// File location starts with "file:///storage/app_name/..."
                            console.log('image is stored in: 'thefile.toURL())
                        },
                        function (error) {
                            alert("upload error code: " + error.code);
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        },
        function (error) {
            alert("filesystem error");
        }
    );
},
```

To retrieve the downloaded image I use the code below: But this code I that URL path "file:///storage...."

```
 getLocalImage(imageUrl){
     let imgName = imageUrl.substring(imageUrl.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
     let image = cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory+"images/"+imgName;
     return image;
 },
```

I tried this method as well:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(
   cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory+"images/"+imgName,
   function (file) {
       image =  file.toURL();
       console.log(image);
       return image;
   },
   function (error) {
       alert("filesystem error");
   }
```

);

Now I want to display such an image in `<img :src="mageHere"`, But all images with "file:///storage/.." are not displaying.